# ArcGIS Flex application - toggling service layers with AS3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, flex

I'm working on an application that has to access data from a server. The flex application uses Esri's World_Imagery basemap and is able to access my data from the ArcGIS for Server, running locally on the same machine.

There are [multiple layers to the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jf75.jpg) that are be displayed, and I would like to toggle them from ActionScript. What is the best way to do this? I've taken a look at the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/flex/sample-code/dynamic-map-layers-on-off.htm), but it's unclear to me how to go about doing this without the preset widgets that Esri provides.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:esri="http://www.esri.com/2008/ags" pageTitle="Example - dynamic maps on top of projected map tiles">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            var b:Boolean = false;
            if (b) {
                //Show Pennwell_PowerPlants
            } else {
                //Hide Pennwell_PowerPlants
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <esri:Map level="3" wrapAround180="true">
        <esri:center>
            <esri:WebMercatorMapPoint lon="0" lat="0" />
        </esri:center>
        <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer url="http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer" />
        <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer url="http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Pennwell_Substations/MapServer" />
        <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer url="http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Pennwell_PowerPlants/MapServer" />
    </esri:Map>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give your map "layers" IDs. toggle the visibility on/off via the "visible" option. eg.

penwellPowerStations.visible=false; // hide it